# Escaping only double quotes and less-than sign

Tags: javascript, xss

Well I came across an interesting escaping...

```
function escape(s) {
    var text = s.replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
    return text;
}
<img alt="(input string passed to function ecape())" src="blahblahblah.jpg">
```

Usually people tell me that you need to ascape both `<` and `>` and the `&` but in this case neither `&` and `>` are escaped

It is possible to inject a script and call `alert(1)`?

Sorry if I haven't made myself clear :D

Comment: Can you explain how you make use of `escape()` function? However escaping string should never be done only via javascript, one can potentially bypass the control.

Comment: @Jonathan What I mean is that the server gets your input, calls function `escape(input)` and then places the returned string inside the alt attribute - Consider it as double quote and '<' escaping but you can still use '&' and '>'

Comment: in simple words, do you want to escape some characters in the string?